# How do I extract characters from one file based on header and values in a list in python?

Tags: python

I have a huge file that Looks like this:

```
-HVC1 tank
Contains300gallons
-HVC2 tank
Contains20gallonsofgasand220galonsofkero
```

And second file which I have read into a list of lists that looks like this:

```
s = [['-HVC1', '0', '8'], ['-HVC1', '12', '18'], ['-HVC2', '9', '17']]
```

I need to compare the positions of each character in the file associated with a given line e.g -HVC1 or -HVC2
to see if it matches HVC1 or HCV2 etc in the list. Based on that, extract the characters in the range of the other 2 values in the list e.g 0, 8; 12,18; 9,17

The expected result for this example list is :

```
-HVC1
Contains
-HVC1
gallons
-HVC2
20gallons
```

My Code:

```
import csv

sequence =[]
with open('my_huge_file', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    dic = {}
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('-'):
            tx = line.split('tank', 1)[0] #include everything before tank in header
        else:
            gh = line[:-1]
            dic[tx] = gh

    s = [['-HVC1', '0', '8'], ['-HVC1', '12', '18'], ['-HVC2', '9', '17']]
    for i in s:
        seq =[]
        for m, n in dic.items():
            for j, k in enumerate(n):
                if int(i[1]) <= j <= int(i[2]) and m == i[0]:
                    seq.append(k)
        sequence.append(seq)
print(sequence)
```

I am getting an empty list of lists in return.

```
[[], [], [], []]
```

I know I am doing something wrong but my logic does make sense, I think. Any help will be appreciated (better with explanation)
The result of the print sequence should be :

```
[[Contains], [gallons], [20gallons]]
```

Which I will then format to the expected result shown above

Comment: what is ``f1`` in ``csv.reader``?

Comment: f1 is the other file i read into a list. maybe I just remove that then so just read the list

Comment: What exactly is the output of `print(sequence)`?

Comment: The result of the print sequence should be a list of the result of the comparisons. which I will then format as shown above in the expected result. but if it can directly go to the above-expected result, I will not mind

Comment: Yes my result based on my code was an empty list of lists [[], [], [], []]

Comment: But what *is* it now? Please copy that into your question, so that we can see what the problem is.

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging. Add some print statements to see what `i, m, n, j, k` are. Apparently either `n` is "empty" (so that `enumerate(n)` has zero iterations), or the `if int(i[1] ...` condition is never true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mkreiger1 comment is correct: debugging helps a lot in this cases.

The problem is in the comparison `m == i[0]`: in the first iteration `m` is `'-HVC1 '` while `i[0]` is `'-HVC1'`. Thus the comparison is always `False`. The solution is to strip the white spaces:

```
lines = ['-HVC1 tank', 'Contains300gallons', '-HVC2 tank',
        'Contains20gallonsofgasand220galonsofkero']

sequence = []
dic = {}
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith('-'):
        tx = line.split('tank', 1)[0]
    else:
        gh = line[:-1]
        # THE FIX IS HERE: Strip the white spaces in ``tx``
        dic[tx.strip()] = gh

s = [['-HVC1', '0', '8'], ['-HVC1', '12', '18'], ['-HVC2', '9', '17']]
for i in s:
    seq = []
    for m, n in dic.items():
        for j, k in enumerate(n):
            if (int(i[1]) <= j <= int(i[2])) and (m == i[0]):
                seq.append(k)
    sequence.append(seq)

print(sequence)
```

Output:

```
[['C', 'o', 'n', 't', 'a', 'i', 'n', 's', '3'], ['a', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'n'], ['0', 'g', 'a', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'n', 's', 'o']]
```

Comment: Yes, thank you much. Just stripping the whitespace provided my desired result. I have searched the whole of stack overflow for an answer but none related.

Comment: Glad to be of help. If this solves your issue, please accept the answer. ps: If you want to invest some time, there are a number of changes that can be done to improve readability and performance, but this is out of scope right now

Comment: Yes, I have accepted. I got a downvote maybe deservedly so. I should have looked at the code in much detail

Comment: You Upvoted, not accepted :D. Anyway: I don't think that the downvote is deserved. However, always try to provide a standalone/working code, so that people can just copy and run it.

Comment: :) Sorry, I am not sure I have done that before. I will look now. Your comment is well noted and I will make sure I provide a copy and run code next time. I learn everyday.

Comment: On answers to your questions, under the arrows to vote, you should see a grey tick mark: you can click it to accept answers